# How to sort list by the second value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this and I want to sort it by the second value.

```
lst = [[x, 5], [y, 1], [z, 6]]
```

like this

```
lst = [[z,6],[x,5],[y,1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two simplest ways to achieve that:

- [*In-place*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inplace-operator-in-python) operation with a [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method:

```py
lst.sort(key=lambda l: l[1], reverse=True)
```

- or with a [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in operation that builds(*) a new sorted list from an iterable:

```py
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda l: l[1], reverse=True)
```

The `reverse=True` parameter is necessary for this case to achieve descending order (the default value for this parameter for both functions is equal `False`, which ends up with an ascending order).

(*) That means you can assign the copy of the list to another variable to have sorted (`new_lst`) and non-sorted (`lst`) list:

```py
new_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda l: l[1], reverse=True)
```

---

To **speed up** the process, you can use an [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) method. You can execute it by importing the method (`from operator import itemgetter`) and changing the value for the `key` parameter:

```py
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

```py
sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
lst = sorted(lst, key= lambda elem : elem[1], reverse=True)
```

From the doc itself:

`sorted`: Returns a new sorted list from the items in iterable.

Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword arguments.

`key`: specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, `key=<lambda_function>`). The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

`reverse`: is a boolean value. If set to True, then the list elements are sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

Comment: The statement has no effect until you assign it to a specified variable. Only `lst = sorted(lst, key= lambda elem : elem[1], reverse=True)` will change the `lst` list.

Comment: Edited as per your feedback, @maciejwww

Answer (score 0):

[sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a new list. If you want to sort the list in place, then you can use [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort).

```py
lst.sort(reverse=True, key= lambda elem : elem[1])
```